# MSSQL GETDATE, return last Year (Number only) from previous month

Tags: sql-server

I need to return the year (number) for the previous month. Like 15-Jan-2023, returns 2022.
Simple but I could not find any related solution.
So far I´m using -31 days but this is not as good as February I need to take care and adjust.

< year(getdate()-32)

Comment: [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)/[`YEAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
```

example:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,'15-JAN-2023'))
```

returns 2022

Comment: Just be aware this conversion of anything with an English month name will fail in most languages other than `us_english`, `british`, etc.